# FPC not working

Tags: full-page-cache, ce-1.9.2.2, redis

I have installed Redis on my local Ubuntu system and configured redis with my magento 1.9.2.2 to store Cache, sessions and FPC. 
For FPC I have installed Mirasvit extension.
I can clearly see the session and cache data in the redis databases. But there is no FPC data in redis, also there is no fpc data in var folder as well.
FPC is working as I can see "cache hit" message on the frontend and also in the logs.
First of all how can I check where the FPC data getting stored?  
Secondly, how can I store it in Redis? 
My **local.xml**

```
<config>
    <global>
        <install>
            <date><![CDATA[Tue, 14 Jun 2016 10:44:20 +0000]]></date>
        </install>
        <crypt>
            <key><![CDATA[f51f9996d9dcdff6d535c453ab4dc301]]></key>
        </crypt>
        <disable_local_modules>false</disable_local_modules>
        <resources>
            <db>
                <table_prefix><![CDATA[]]></table_prefix>
            </db>
            <default_setup>
                <connection>
                    <host><![CDATA[localhost]]></host>
                    <username><![CDATA[root]]></username>
                    <password><![CDATA[root]]></password>
                    <dbname><![CDATA[magento1922]]></dbname>
                    <initStatements><![CDATA[SET NAMES utf8]]></initStatements>
                    <model><![CDATA[mysql4]]></model>
                    <type><![CDATA[pdo_mysql]]></type>
                    <pdoType><![CDATA[]]></pdoType>
                    <active>1</active>
                </connection>
            </default_setup>
        </resources>
        <!--<session_save><![CDATA[files]]></session_save>-->

        <cache>
          <backend>Cm_Cache_Backend_Redis</backend>
          <backend_options>
            <server>127.0.0.1</server>              <!-- or absolute path to unix socket -->
            <port>6379</port>
            <persistent></persistent>               <!-- Specify a unique string like "cache-db0" to enable persistent connections. -->
            <database>0</database>
            <password></password>
            <force_standalone>0</force_standalone>  <!-- 0 for phpredis, 1 for standalone PHP -->
            <connect_retries>1</connect_retries>    <!-- Reduces errors due to random connection failures -->
            <read_timeout>10</read_timeout>         <!-- Set read timeout duration -->
            <automatic_cleaning_factor>0</automatic_cleaning_factor> <!-- Disabled by default -->
            <compress_data>1</compress_data>        <!-- 0-9 for compression level, recommended: 0 or 1 -->
            <compress_tags>1</compress_tags>        <!-- 0-9 for compression level, recommended: 0 or 1 -->
            <compress_threshold>20480</compress_threshold>  <!-- Strings below this size will not be compressed -->
            <compression_lib>gzip</compression_lib> <!-- Supports gzip, lzf and snappy -->
          </backend_options>
        </cache>

        <full_page_cache>
          <backend>Cm_Cache_Backend_Redis</backend>
          <backend_options>
            <server>127.0.0.1</server>              <!-- or absolute path to unix socket -->
            <port>6379</port>
            <persistent></persistent>               <!-- Specify unique string to enable persistent connections. E.g.: sess-db0; bugs with phpredis and php-fpm are known: https://github.com/nicolasff/phpredis/issues/70 -->
            <database>1</database>                  <!-- Redis database number; protection against accidental data loss is improved by not sharing databases -->
            <password></password>                   <!-- Specify if your Redis server requires authentication -->
            <force_standalone>0</force_standalone>  <!-- 0 for phpredis, 1 for standalone PHP -->
            <connect_retries>1</connect_retries>    <!-- Reduces errors due to random connection failures -->
            <lifetimelimit>57600</lifetimelimit>    <!-- 16 hours of lifetime for cache record -->
            <compress_data>0</compress_data>        <!-- DISABLE compression for EE FPC since it already uses compression -->
          </backend_options>
        </full_page_cache>

        <!-- other configuration nodes -->
        <session_save>db</session_save>
        <redis_session>                       <!-- All options seen here are the defaults -->
            <host>127.0.0.1</host>            <!-- Specify an absolute path if using a unix socket -->
            <port>6379</port>
            <password></password>             <!-- Specify if your Redis server requires authentication -->
            <timeout>2.5</timeout>            <!-- This is the Redis connection timeout, not the locking timeout -->
            <persistent></persistent>         <!-- Specify unique string to enable persistent connections. -->
            <db>2</db>                        <!-- Redis database number; protection from accidental loss is improved by using a unique DB number for sessions -->
            <compression_threshold>2048</compression_threshold>  <!-- Set to 0 to disable compression (recommended when suhosin.session.encrypt=on); known bug with strings over 64k: https://github.com/colinmollenhour/Cm_Cache_Backend_Redis/issues/18 -->
            <compression_lib>gzip</compression_lib>              <!-- gzip, lzf or snappy -->
            <log_level>4</log_level>               <!-- 0 (emergency: system is unusable), 4 (warning; additional information, recommended), 5 (notice: normal but significant condition), 6 (info: informational messages), 7 (debug: the most information for development/testing) -->
            <max_concurrency>6</max_concurrency>                 <!-- maximum number of processes that can wait for a lock on one session; for large production clusters, set this to at least 10% of the number of PHP processes -->
            <break_after_frontend>5</break_after_frontend>       <!-- seconds to wait for a session lock in the frontend; not as critical as admin -->
            <break_after_adminhtml>30</break_after_adminhtml>
            <bot_lifetime>7200</bot_lifetime>                    <!-- Bots get shorter session lifetimes. 0 to disable -->
        </redis_session> 
        <!-- other configuration nodes --> 

    </global>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <frontName><![CDATA[admin]]></frontName>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
</config>
```

Comment: RTFM !!!!  https://mirasvit.com/doc/fpc/1.0.12/configuration/fpc.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing `<full_page_cache>` to `<fpc>` resolved my issue. 
Now I can see FPC data getting saved in redis.

Comment: this is a paid extension you must ask extension developer for configuration examples!